# How to select nth row in CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

If I use something like a `SERIAL` (which is a random number) for my table's primary key, how can I select a numbered row from my table? In MySQL, I just use the auto incremented ID to select a specific row, but not sure how to approach the problem with an arbitrary numbering sequence.

For reference, here is the table I'm working with:

```
+--------------------+------+-------+
|         id         | name | score |
+--------------------+------+-------+
| 235451721728983041 | ABC  |  1000 |
| 235451721729015809 | EDF  |  1100 |
| 235451721729048577 | GHI  |  1200 |
| 235451721729081345 | JKL  |   900 |
+--------------------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses will return the nth row. For example `SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY col1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9` returns the 10th row.

Note that it’s important to include the `ORDER BY` clause here because you care about the order of the results (if you don’t include `ORDER BY`, it’s possible that the results are arbitrarily ordered).

If you care about the order in which things were inserted, you could `ORDER BY` the `SERIAL` column (`id` in your case), though it’s not always the case because transaction contention and other things could cause the generated `SERIAL` values to not be strictly ordered.